# Android studio ListView default items

Tags: java, android, listview

When I put a `ListView` on the XML like this:

```
    <ListView
    android:id="@+id/list"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"/>
```

and I haven't put the items in from the MainActivity, but it already gives me the default items from 1 to 8 (like screenshot) even if I use `ArrayAdapter` in `MainActivity`, it's still not changing the `ListView`.

[image]

Any help on this would be appreciated.

Comment: you need to show the code you have written

Comment: You need to have an adapter class for it. Show us your ArrayAdapter.

Comment: thank you guys, just solve the problem. it turns out that I use cellphone to run the app, it shows the correct ListView that I working on.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As per the screenshot you have posted, it is the result of the listview not being properly initialized.

Your layout should look something like this

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
   xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
   android:layout_width="match_parent"
   android:layout_height="match_parent"
   android:orientation="vertical"
   tools:context=".ListActivity" >

   <ListView
      android:id="@+id/mobile_list"
      android:layout_width="match_parent"
      android:layout_height="wrap_content" >
   </ListView>

</LinearLayout>
```

Your MainActivity should look something like this

```
    import android.os.Bundle;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;
import android.widget.ListView;

public class MainActivity extends Activity {
   // Array of strings...
   String[] mobileArray = {"Android","IPhone","WindowsMobile","Blackberry",
      "WebOS","Ubuntu","Windows7","Max OS X"};

   @Override
   protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
      super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
      setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

      ArrayAdapter adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, 
         R.layout.activity_listview, mobileArray);

      ListView listView = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.mobile_list);
      listView.setAdapter(adapter);
   }
}
```

And your listview item layout resource file should look something like this

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<!--  Single List Item Design -->

<TextView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
   android:id="@+id/label"
   android:layout_width="fill_parent"
   android:layout_height="fill_parent"
   android:padding="10dip"
   android:textSize="16dip"
   android:textStyle="bold" >
</TextView>
```

This should help you to understand how it functions. For more, check this https://www.tutorialspoint.com/android/android_list_view.htm

Comment: thank you, just solve the problem. it turns out that I use cellphone to run the app, it shows the correct ListView that I working on.